# Reordering rows of a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a 3D array of values like this:

```
[[[ 0  0  1  0 -1  1  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  0  1 -1 -1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  1 -2 -1  1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  2  1 -1  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 -2  0  0 -1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  1  0 -1  1  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  2  1 -1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  1 -2 -1  1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  0  1 -1 -1  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]]
```

I need to reshape it so that all the first rows in every matrix is group together in a matrix then all the second rows, etc.

So that the result looks like:

```
[[[ 0  0  1  0 -1  1  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  1  0 -1  1  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0 -1  0  1 -1 -1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  2  1 -1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  1 -2 -1  1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 -2  0  0 -1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  1 -2 -1  1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0 -1  2  1 -1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 -1  0  1 -1 -1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]]
```

Comment: Why not give a more concise example? Is it really necessary to understand your problem to give such a big matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to [swap the first two axes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) of your array `x`. If the array is an `ndarray` (as yours is), a view is returned and no data is copied:

```
>>> x.swapaxes(0,1)
```

For example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

>>> x.swapaxes(0,1)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```